# How to call html page when I click on link in a cell rendered through cellrendererframework in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6 and I have a main component of users. I have an aggrid and one of the columns should be icon for edit. I create a separate cellrendereframeork component in which I have template with link and on click it calls method in the same component. I am able to render col with edit link and also on click of the link I am able to go to the method I created and see that that particular row data is displayed. But instead of just viewing the data on click of the icon I need to go to a different page to edit the users. How do I achieve this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: In user.component.ts I have const columnDefs=[ {headerName=‘UserName’, field=‘username’}’                  {headerName=‘’, cellRendererFramework: EditCellRendererCompoment}];                                              In EditCellRendererComponent.ts I have                              selector: ‘edit-cell-renderer.component,                             template: ‘<a (click)=“editRow()”><i class=“fa fa-wrench”></I></a>

Comment: This displays icon in each row of the grid and I am able to click it as I have marked it as <a>. On click it goes to the editRow method in editcellrenderercompoment and I am able to display the data of the row on which this icon was clicked. But what I want is on click another component should be called which is another screen with username field to update the name instead of just displaying the value of the row. I should also be able to pass the row data to the edit screen as well

Comment: Hello Anne, as I asked before, **Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment** , as it will probably be unreadable. You are unlikely to get any useful responses if you don't give people the information that they need in an accessible form.

Comment: Ya I did put the code for columnDef and editcellrenderercomponent as well in the comment

Comment: can anyone help me on this?